# Using StringRequest to POST to Google Sheet via GScript. GScript works but app stalls

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, post

I am trying to build an Android app with a simple form submission system, based on the following tutorial; https://www.crazycodersclub.com/android/how-to-use-google-sheet-as-database-for-android-app-1-insert-operation/

I've succesfully created the app and it launches fine in the Android VM. But when I fill out the submission fields, and press the "Submit" button, it simply shows the progressdialog without actually sending the POST request to the Google Script page. I've checked that the script functions using PostMan, and there are no errors on that end. How do I tackle this? I just want it to submit to the Google sheet.

I am a total beginner to Android development, so bear over with me.

Here are the app scripts;

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gsheetitem">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.gsheetitem.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.gsheetitem.add_item"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

AddItem.Java

```
    package com.example.gsheetitem;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class add_item extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    EditText editTextItemName,editTextBrand;
    Button buttonAddItem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_item);

        editTextItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_item_name);
        editTextBrand = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_brand);

        buttonAddItem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
        buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    //This is the part where data is transafeered from Your Android phone to Sheet by using HTTP Rest API calls

    private void   addItemToSheet() {

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Item","Please wait");
        final String name = editTextItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String brand = editTextBrand.getText().toString().trim();




        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "***LINK_TO_GOOGLE_SHEET_GOES_HERE***",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(add_item.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.gsheetitem.MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

                //here we pass params
                parmas.put("action","addItem");
                parmas.put("itemName",name);
                parmas.put("brand",brand);

                return parmas;
            }
        };

        int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds

        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==buttonAddItem){
            addItemToSheet();

            //Define what to do when button is clicked
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gsheetitem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttonAddItem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonAddItem = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
        buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==buttonAddItem){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), add_item.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

add_Item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/et_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Brand"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_item_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_brand" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gsheetitem"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'}
```

The app looks like this;

[Landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AukoH.jpg)

[Submission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySaDk.jpg)

[Progressdialog that never ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV0cb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, but in my case, it had a simple issue that my emulator was not able to access internet connection from my laptop.

to get the internet connection to emulator from laptop:
https://medium.com/@cafonsomota/android-emulator-when-theres-no-connection-to-the-internet-129e8b63b7ce

you should try it on a real android device with an internet connection by either building an apk of your app or connecting your mobile to your laptop in debugging mode, then you'll be able to see connected mobile in the Run menu of android-studio in select devices.

to build apk for testing
https://medium.com/@ashutosh.vyas/create-unsigned-apk-in-android-325fef3b0d0a